# Something like \hfill with pstricks and XeTeX

Tags: spacing, xetex, pstricks

I have a line of text in a `pspicture` environment and I need to distribute the words in a way like `\hfill` could do. Here is an image of what I want:

[image]

I currently have this minimal example

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(12,3)

\psline(1,1)(11,1)
\rput[Bl]{0}(1,1){Word LongWord Words MuchLongerWord}

% command which draws the grid and labels it
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0, griddots=10, gridlabels=12pt]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Which compiles to this (using another font):
[image]

How should I enhance it to get the desired result?

**Condition**: I need it to compile with `xelatex` (which, as far as [I have read](http://en.it-usenet.org/thread/16747/9863/), doesn't like the idea of putting text on a path) so I can't experiment with `pst-text` much.

I don't necessarily need to place the text on any path. I essentially only need to equally **distribute the words in** a certain amount of **horizontal space**. Any ideas how to get there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `\makebox` with Option `s` (stretch).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=2cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(12,3)

\psline(1,1)(11,1)
\rput[Bl]{0}(1,1){\makebox[10cm][s]{Word LongWord Words MuchLongerWord}}

% command which draws the grid and labels it
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0, griddots=10, gridlabels=12pt]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]